# React native datepicker plugin throws an error("Property has a previous declaration") for iOS build on Xcode 12

Tags: react-native

React native datepicker plugin throws an error("Property has a previous declaration") for iOS build on Xcode 12. This issue happened after the new xcode version 12

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Change #import "UIView+React.h" to #import "React/UIView+React.h" in react-native-date-picker/ios/RNDatePicker/RNDatePickerManager.m
2. Change #import "UIView+React.h" to #import "React/UIView+React.h" in react-native-date-picker/ios/RNDatePicker/DatePicker.m